# Any yasnippet to evaluate infix math expression?

Tags: yasnippet, calc

I would like to have a yasnippet to evaluate infix math expression on the current line.  E.g., If the line is `1 + 2 =` and I trigger yasnippet at the end of line, it will append the result at the end: `1 + 2 = 3`.

I found this snippet from  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6u0gmx

```
$1 = ${1:$(calc-eval
   (replace-regexp-in-string "p" "perm"
                 (replace-regexp-in-string "c" "choose"
                                   yas-text)))}$0
```

But it's a real-time interactive snippet that I don't prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

a simple way to make it work in the middle of a line (that does not contain any other number of parentheses before the formula) is to replace the `(line-beginning-position)` with:

```lisp
(save-excursion
(beginning-of-line)
(1- (re-search-forward "[0-9(]")))
```

Of course if you are trying to evaluate a formula starting with a letter (e.g. sin(2)), then surround it with parentheses.

END EDIT

The documentation for the Yasnippet Template Syntax can be found [here](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#org9801aa7).

Then we can easily modify the snippet of in your example to achieve what you want as follows

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: =
# key: =
# --
= `(calc-eval
(buffer-substring-no-properties
(line-beginning-position)
(- (point) 2)))`$0
```

Note that you must add a space before `=` to make it get recognized as a (trigger) 'key'. Also, this example assumes that the line contains only the expression. If you would like to use the expansion on a line with additional text, then you should extend the logic in this snippet.

Comment: It works, thanks!